# Hover effects delayed though no transition used

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I am working on a website where i have to display text overlay on images on hover. Although i have not used transition property still hover effects show up after a lot of time. Solution for this problem required.Thanks

I have no clue on what i should try.I am expecting the hover effects to show immediately

Comment: Seeing some code you've got so far would be really helpful ;)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.